# Core data migration - Appstore build crashing on iOS 8 devices, working on iOS 9

Tags: swift, core-data, core-data-migration

My app store update build is crashing, it's a core data crash but I am getting this crash on only iOS 8 devices, it is working fine on iOS 9 devices. 
I have correctly performed light weight migration as well added the new model version keeping the old one as a base, added the dictionary in options as well while adding "addPersistentStoreWithType".

**ManagedObjectModel**

```
lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("abcProject", withExtension: "momd")
    NSLog("Url is -  \(modelURL)")
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)!
}()
```

**PersistentStoreCoordinator**

```
 lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("abcProject")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
        NSLog("TEST564 - 7 URL - \(url)")
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: mOptions)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("TEST564 Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    } catch {
        fatalError()
        NSLog("TEST564 FATAL error")

    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

Above is my set of code for reference. I have searched everywhere and I get details about the light weight migration only.

**Following is the device log after crash:-**

```
> Jul 19 11:25:00 iPhone abcProject-Production[211] <Warning>: CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) 

URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B12FCDA6-C91B-487E-8D03-CBBEB884996D/Documents/abcProject options:{
NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" 

UserInfo=0x16b05490 {URL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B12FCDA6-C91B-487E-8D03-CBBEB884996D/Documents/abcProject, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        TabBanner = <3722cf8b 4ac58f43 20c84d7e 7d66865d a1382ecc 1ab25190 7b7c3fa7 843813fe>;
        Video = <c51795f8 140c4936 de1b7615 03a944e7 f2b0451f 3c0b5887 2cfb31d3 07610d22>;
    };NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "79788D63-BEF2-4339-BF60-1580904D9B44";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store} with userInfo dictionary {
URL = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B12FCDA6-C91B-487E-8D03-CBBEB884996D/Documents/abcProject";
metadata =     {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
        TabBanner = <3722cf8b 4ac58f43 20c84d7e 7d66865d a1382ecc 1ab25190 7b7c3fa7 843813fe>;
        Video = <c51795f8 140c4936 de1b7615 03a944e7 f2b0451f 3c0b5887 2cfb31d3 07610d22>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "79788D63-BEF2-4339-BF60-1580904D9B44";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
};
reason = "Can't find model for source store";
}


Jul 19 11:25:00 iPhone abcProject-Production[211] <Warning>: CoreData: annotation: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's current model hashes are {
TabBanner = <2efd2387 6f370f71 d585132f 9d6aa8fe afcdc841 ef6e9b89 396625d1 cbc99cea>;
Video = <c51795f8 140c4936 de1b7615 03a944e7 f2b0451f 3c0b5887 2cfb31d3 07610d22>;
}

Jul 19 11:25:00 iPhone abcProject-Production[211] <Warning>: Unresolved error Optional(Error Domain=YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN Code=9999 "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" UserInfo=0x168e0c90 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError=0x16b05350 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.}), [NSLocalizedDescription: Failed to initialize the application's saved data, NSUnderlyingError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" 

UserInfo=0x16b05490 {URL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B12FCDA6-C91B-487E-8D03-CBBEB884996D/Documents/abcProject, metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    TabBanner = <3722cf8b 4ac58f43 20c84d7e 7d66865d a1382ecc 1ab25190 7b7c3fa7 843813fe>;
    Video = <c51795f8 140c4936 de1b7615 03a944e7 f2b0451f 3c0b5887 2cfb31d3 07610d22>;
};

NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);

NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "79788D63-BEF2-4339-BF60-1580904D9B44";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store}, NSLocalizedFailureReason: There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data.]
Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone ReportCrash[212] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone ReportCrash[212] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 211

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone ReportCrash[212] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process abcProject-Production[211]

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection invalid

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 211: No such process

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 211: No such process

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone mediaserverd[37] <Notice>: '' com.abcProject(pid = 211) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone wifid[69] <Notice>: WiFi:[490600501.266659]: Foreground Network Application exited.

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone AppStore[175] <Warning>: [SSMetricsEventController] Direct-access controller is calling through XPC to flush Unreported Events

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone wifid[69] <Notice>: WiFi:[490600501.267352]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: apsd itunesstored networkd

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.abcProject[0xb6e0][211]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.abcProject[0xb6e0]) <Notice>: Service only ran for 6 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 2147483641 seconds.

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.abcProject[0xb6e0]' crashed.

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone assertiond[58] <Warning>: pid_suspend failed for <BKNewProcess: 0x1668b480; com.abcProject; pid: 211; hostpid: -1>: Unknown error: -1, Unknown error: -1

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone assertiond[58] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x1668b480; com.abcProject; pid: 211; hostpid: -1> to 2, priority: No such process

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone assertiond[58] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x1668b480; com.abcProject; pid: 211; hostpid: -1> to 4096, priority: No such process

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone UserEventAgent[17] <Warning>: id=com.abcProject pid=211, state=0

Jul 19 11:25:01 iPhone ReportCrash[212] <Notice>: Saved report to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/abcProject-Production_2016-07-19-112501_iPhone.ips

Jul 19 11:25:06 iPhone wifid[69] <Notice>: WiFi:[490600506.681414]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"

Jul 19 11:25:06 iPhone wifid[69] <Notice>: WiFi:[490600506.686744]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"

Jul 19 11:25:06 iPhone wifid[69] <Notice>: WiFi:[490600506.743193]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd"

Jul 19 11:25:08 iPhone wifid[69] <Notice>: WiFi:[490600508.843256]: Client itunesstored set type to normal application

Jul 19 11:25:08 iPhone wifid[69] <Notice>: WiFi:[490600508.844080]: __WiFiManagerSetEnableState: state TRUE, manager->enable.setting TRUE, manager->unlockedSinceBoot TRUE

Jul 19 11:25:08 iPhone wifid[69] <Notice>: WiFi:[490600508.845449]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: apsd networkd

Jul 19 11:25:09 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0

Jul 19 11:25:12 iPhone aggregated[29] <Warning>: Scheduling parameters: 0 minutes before midnight, 4.0 time(s)/day

Jul 19 11:25:12 iPhone aggregated[29] <Warning>: delay: 595 into interval 21600 => 22195

Jul 19 11:25:12 iPhone aggregated[29] <Warning>: Next ADDaily run scheduled in 06:09:55 at 2016-07-19 12:05:07 +0000

Jul 19 11:25:12 iPhone addaily[213] <Warning>: addaily started

Jul 19 11:25:12 iPhone addaily[213] <Warning>: daily tasks for day 17000

Jul 19 11:25:13 iPhone addaily[213] <Warning>: Filtering only beta sessions

Jul 19 11:25:13 iPhone addaily[213] <Warning>: Saved Sessions as /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/log-sessions-2016-07-19-112513.session

Jul 19 11:25:23 iPhone addaily[213] <Warning>: addaily ended
```

Comment: Do you have any detail at all about the crash? Right now it's not even clear what indicates that the crash is due to migration.

Comment: I have edited the question with the complete device log crash after install.
Please have a look into it and let me know if you are able to find the issue . 
Thanks

Comment: I am also facing same issue.Migration works on iOS 9 device but crashing on iOS 8 devices.

Comment: @DesertRose - Can u please send the same two set of codes which I have put , for my reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it resolved by doing a simple change .

**Earlier code** :-

```
url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("abcProject1")
```

**Fixed code** :-

```
url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("abcProject1.sqlite")
```

adding <**.sqlite**> extension to my url path solved the issue for me. 
It is fully tested with all the possible scenarios. 
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The error, `Can't find model for source store` says that when the app tried to migrate the persistent store, it could not find the data model that had been used to create the store. Data migration requires both the old and new data stores. The old one is used to load the data, and the new one is used to update the data for future use.

The reason this works on iOS 9 is that iOS 9 added model caching for use in lightweight migrations of SQLite stores. On iOS 9 you can therefore get a successful migration without the old model, because the old version will be automatically cached. This feature was not available on iOS 8, so if you're still supporting 8 then you still need to include the old version of the model in your app.

Comment: Thank you so much - Yes that is what I thought 
but the thing is I have all the data model from starting , I have did this migration with same scenarios for the other projects and they are working fine I am sure there has to be  a small issue in it.

Comment: Please see my answer , If you could tell me why It worked correctly ?

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the crash I created new database for **iOS 8** because I didnt need existing data that much.

I changed my storeURL from

```
let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("abcProject")
```

to

```
let url:NSURL
if (OS_VERSION<9.0)
{
    url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("abcProject1")
}
else
{
    url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("abcProject")
}
```

This fixed the crash for me.

Comment: Thanks , But I need the existing data so I cannot use this.